# How to SELECT property values in a Box

Tags: objectbox

I am using ObjectBox 1.3.3

How to query for a list of property values for a Box based on some condition?

I can work around by querying for entities that satisfy certain constraints and then build the list of property values from the (query) results. Instead, is there a way to directly filter for the property values?

Thanks,
VS

Comment: This feature is actually just being implemented. Watch for version 1.4 or 1.5.